# How set path for correct work gulp-deporder plugin in scripts?

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-concat

I have a script, in which includes other scripts with gulp-deporder notation:

`/* require
foo/bar.js
*/`

All good, but if the scripts location subfolder, gulp gives out error:

`script.js requires foo/bar.js which was not found`

Scripts is exist of course.

In gulpfile.js, path to script such:

```
folder.src + 'js/**/*.js
```

How resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens when you use **"/"** instead of **"\"** on Windows.
Try changing your code as follow :

```
/* require
foo\bar.js
*/
```